# Avoid script errors in browsing

Tags: c#, xaml

I am developing a web browser, in Visual Studio I have built it in the old format, but when browsing I encounter a high probability of script errors, I would like to recode both XAML and C# in a new way, but I don't know which part to rewrite.

What parts do I need to recode?

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTutorialSamples.Misc_controls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Xebec" Height="300" Width="450" Icon="/favicon.png">
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="NavigationCommands.BrowseBack" CanExecute="BrowseBack_CanExecute" Executed="BrowseBack_Executed" />
        <CommandBinding Command="NavigationCommands.BrowseForward" CanExecute="BrowseForward_CanExecute" Executed="BrowseForward_Executed" />
        <CommandBinding Command="NavigationCommands.GoToPage" CanExecute="GoToPage_CanExecute" Executed="GoToPage_Executed" />
        <CommandBinding Command="NavigationCommands.Refresh" CanExecute="Refresh_CanExecute" Executed="Refresh_Executed" />
        <CommandBinding Command="NavigationCommands.BrowseHome" CanExecute="BrowseHome_CanExecute" Executed="BrowseHome_Executed" />
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <DockPanel>
        <ToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Button Command="NavigationCommands.BrowseBack">
                    <Image Source="/arrow_left.png" Width="16" Height="16" />
                </Button>
                <Button Command="NavigationCommands.BrowseForward">
                    <Image Source="/arrow_right.png" Width="16" Height="16" />
                </Button>
            <Button Command="NavigationCommands.Refresh">
                <Image Source="/refreshicon.png" Width="16" Height="16" />
            </Button>
            <Button Command="NavigationCommands.BrowseHome">
                <Image Source="/homeicon.png" Width="16" Height="14" />
            </Button>
            <Separator />
                <TextBox Name="txtUrl" Width="300" KeyUp="txtUrl_KeyUp" />
            <Button Command="NavigationCommands.GoToPage">
                <Image Source="/searchicon.png" Width="16" Height="16" />
            </Button>
        </ToolBar>
        <Grid>
            <WebBrowser Name="WebBrowser" Navigating="WebBrowser_Navigating"></WebBrowser>
            </Grid>
        </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

*MainWindow.xaml.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfTutorialSamples.Misc_controls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// MainWindow.xaml の相互作用ロジック
    /// </summary>
    public partial class WebBrowserControlSample : Window
    {
        public WebBrowserControlSample()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            WebBrowser.Navigate("http://www.bing.com");
        }

        private void txtUrl_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUrl.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtUrl.Text)) {
                    WebBrowser.Navigate(txtUrl.Text);
                }
        }
        
        private void WebBrowser_Navigating(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            txtUrl.Text = e.Uri.OriginalString;
        }

        private void BrowseBack_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = ((WebBrowser != null) && (WebBrowser.CanGoBack));
        }

        private void BrowseBack_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowser.GoBack();
        }

        private void BrowseForward_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = ((WebBrowser != null) && (WebBrowser.CanGoForward));
        }

        private void BrowseForward_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowser.GoForward();
        }

        private void GoToPage_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }

        private void GoToPage_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowser.Navigate(txtUrl.Text);
        }


        private void Refresh_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }

        private void Refresh_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowser.Refresh();
        }



        private void BrowseHome_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }

        private void BrowseHome_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowser.Navigate("http://www.bing.com");
        }



    }
}
```

P.S.

I'm not twisted. My browser randomly throws an error dialog when browsing the sites. It can't load the Java script. The designs and layouts of the sites are also broken. I can't figure out why.

`ActiveX` or `ScriptErrorsSuppressed` makes sense.
Script error messages are now avoided.

However, when browsing, the design and layout of the sites you are browsing are clearly broken.
If there is a way to not only bypass the error dialogs, but also make the design and layout of the sites you browse look normal, please suggest me.

Comment: What script errors do you get?  Please don't make us guess.

Answer (score -1):

Inside `WebBrowser_Navigating` handler you can put this piece of code to suppress script errors:

```
private void WebBrowser_Navigating(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    txtUrl.Text = e.Uri.OriginalString;

    // Suppress script errors
    // webBrowser1 is your WebBrowser control name
    dynamic activeX = webBrowser1.GetType().InvokeMember("ActiveXInstance", BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                                                         null,
                                                         webBrowser1,
                                                         new object[] { });
    activeX.Silent = true;
}
```

Comment: First, their web browser instance is called "WebBrowser".  Second, you don't need to go through activeX.  You can set `WebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;`.

Comment: @Tim Roberts, feel free to put your suggestion as an answer.

Comment: @Auditive
Thanks for the good suggestions. The script error log is no longer displayed. However, the design and graphics of the sites I randomly visit are still broken. Is there any way to get them to display properly?

Comment: @Tim Roberts,

Thank you very much. The error dialog is now hidden. I'm having problems with the randomly broken layouts of the sites I'm browsing, so please let me know if you have some elegant code to make them appear correctly.

Comment: To be honest, how can we possibly know what the issues are with "randomly broken layouts"?  The `WebBrowser` ActiveX control is based on Internet Explorer, and IE doesn't always produce great results.

Comment: @Zigzakk, note that WebBrowser control utilizes default Internet Explorer browser. You probably should look for much modern browser controls, such as CEFSharp, based on Chromium.